# Simplify loop computation

Tags: r, loops

Consider the following vector **x**:

```
 > 1:9
 [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

and consider the following inputs:

```
 start = 10
 pmt = 2
```

This is the result (let's call the resulting vector `res`) I am looking to achieve (what's displayed are the actual formulas). Note that the result is a vector not a dataframe. I just displayed it here 2 dimensions.

[image]

In other words, to obtain **res**, you multiple `start` by the cumulative product for each cell of `df` up to the corresponding cell.

When the vector index is a multiple is 4 or 7, the start value gets updated.

This is what I have attempted:

```
     for(i in 1:9) {
         res[i] = start * cumprod(df[k:i])[i]
         if(i %% 3 == 0) {
             start = res[i] - pmt
             k = k + 3
         } else {
             start = res[i]
         }
     }
 }
```

To put the problem into context, imagine you have a start value of money of 10 dollars, and you want to invest it over 9 months. However, you want to make a withdrawal at the end of each 3 months (i.e. at the beginning of month 4, month 7,  ...). The vector *x* represent random values of returns.
Therefore, at the beginning of month 4, your start value is `start*1*2*3` **minus** the withdrawal `pmt`.

The purpose here is computing the wealth value at the end of month 9.

The problem is that in reality, i = 200 (200 months), and I need to redo this computation for 10,000 different vectors **x**. So looping 10,000 times over the above code takes forever to execute!

Would you have any suggestion as to how to compute this more efficiently? I hope the explanation is not too confusing!

Thank you!

Comment: Is this right that `start` should be used only for the first row (1, 2, and 3)?

Comment: yes, exactly. Then the start value gets updated for the subsequent rows.

Comment: why is `- pmt` missing from the first row of computation examples?

Comment: You only start deducting pmt when index is 4 or 7, i.e. when index is multiple of 3 + 1. For example: 4 = 3*1 + 1, and 7 = 3*2 + 1.

Comment: I have just put my problem into a context for better understanding. Please read my updated question! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you work out your formula for `res` as an iterative formula, then it is easier to write a function that you can give to `Reduce`. Here it is as a simple loop

```
x <- 1:9
start <- 10
pmt <- 2

res <- numeric(length(x))
res[1] <- x[1] * start
for (i in seq_along(x)[-1]) {
  res[i] <- (res[i-1] - (pmt * (!(i%%4) || !(i%%7)))) * x[i]
}
```

If you want to write it as a `Reduce` function, it would look like this

```
Reduce(function(r, i) {
  (r - (pmt * (!(i%%4) || !(i%%7)))) * x[i]
}, 
       seq_along(x),
       init = start, 
       accumulate = TRUE)[-1]
```

There is some weirdness with the start values and dropping the first element of the result because of the way that initial values are handled (and that it iteration is over indexes, not values, since comparisons must be done on the index). The loop here is probably more understandable.

Comment: Let me try it ! But I think you got exactly what I was looking for! Thanks

Comment: The iterative formula gives what `res[i]` should be as a function only of `res[i-1]` and `i` (and indirectly `x[i]`). I assumed that the 1, 2, 3, etc. in your formulas were the elements of `x`, because otherwise, `x` wasn't used anywhere.

Comment: Indeed, 1 2 3 were elements of x! Excellent, thank you!! Now, I have a list of vectors ( a list of vectors **x**, if you wish), and I would like to repeat this operation for each element (i.e. vector) of the list. Would you suggest a good way to do that?

Comment: list of vectors in, and want list of vectors out? `lapply(list_of_xs, function(x) {...the whole Reduce call...})`. That will call the `Reduce` call for each element of the list separately, and put the results of the calls into a list.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that, but it takes a few seconds to execute. I guess I can live with that :). +1 for all these great ideas, especially reduce. I can't thank you enough!!

Comment: Sorry, I have one final question. Imagine that you vector x was of length 200, and you deduct `pmt` whenever the index is a multiple of 12 plus 1, i.e. 13, 25, 37, ... How would you adapt the code?

Comment: This is what I tried: `Reduce(function(r, i) { (r - (pmt * ((i%%12 == 1 && i != 1)))) * x[i] }, seq_along(x), init = pv, accumulate = TRUE)[-1]`. Would this be correct?

Comment: @Mariam That looks right for every multiple of 12 plus 1. You can always just check that part by itself to see if the 1's and 0's show up in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

I know you mentioned it being 1d, but I think this works well and you can convert it to 1d very easily -

```
start = 10
pmt = 2

library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(
month = 1:13
)

dt[,principalgrown := start*cumprod(month)]

#explained below#######
dt[,interestlost := 0]
for(i in seq(from = 4, to = (dim(dt)[1]), by = 3))
{
dt[month >= i,interestlost := interestlost + (prod(i:month)), by = month]
}
#######################

dt[,finalamount := principalgrown - (pmt*interestlost)]
```

The part within the #s is the trick. Where you calculate month 7 value as `((1*2*3*start  - pmt)*4*5*6 - pmt) * 7`, i calculate it as `1*2*3*4*5*6*7*start - 4*5*6*7*pmt - 7*pmt`. `1*2*3*4*5*6*7*start` is `principalgrown` and `- 4*5*6*7*pmt - 7*pmt` is `-(pmt*interestlost)`